# Bee Command Not Found after installation of Beetools

Tags: go, installation, beego

I am trying to install beetools for using the Beego framework in Go lang. I have seen the other solutions to this issue and I have added the GOPATH and PATH correctly in my zshrc file. Here is a snapshot of the same. Despite all this, I am still getting command not found after installation of beetools on running bee command.

```
export GOPATH=/Users/yasheelvyas/go
export PATH=$GOPATH/bin:$PATH

#THIS MUST BE AT THE END OF THE FILE FOR SDKMAN TO WORK!!!
export SDKMAN_DIR="/Users/yasheelvyas/.sdkman"
[[ -s "/Users/yasheelvyas/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" ]] && source "/Users/yasheelvyas/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
~
```

Snapshot of my Go environment

```
GO111MODULE="on"
GOARCH="amd64"
GOBIN=""
GOCACHE="/Users/yasheelvyas/Library/Caches/go-build"
GOENV="/Users/yasheelvyas/Library/Application Support/go/env"
GOEXE=""
GOFLAGS=""
GOHOSTARCH="amd64"
GOHOSTOS="darwin"
GOINSECURE=""
GOMODCACHE="/Users/yasheelvyas/go/pkg/mod"
GONOPROXY=""
GONOSUMDB=""
GOOS="darwin"
GOPATH="/Users/yasheelvyas/go"
GOPRIVATE=""
GOPROXY="https://proxy.golang.org,direct"
GOROOT="/usr/local/go"
GOSUMDB="sum.golang.org"
GOTMPDIR=""
GOTOOLDIR="/usr/local/go/pkg/tool/darwin_amd64"
GCCGO="gccgo"
AR="ar"
CC="clang"
CXX="clang++"
CGO_ENABLED="1"
GOMOD="/dev/null"
CGO_CFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_CPPFLAGS=""
CGO_CXXFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_FFLAGS="-g -O2"
CGO_LDFLAGS="-g -O2"
PKG_CONFIG="pkg-config"
GOGCCFLAGS="-fPIC -m64 -pthread -fno-caret-diagnostics -Qunused-arguments -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=/var/folders/xq/g9m87w614b9f4rljpm38jfvh0000gn/T/go-build779147141=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches -fno-common"
```

Comment: Is the bee package installed and exists in your `$GOPATH/bin` directory? What's the output of `ls $GOPATH/bin/bee`?

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic the output is /Users/yasheelvyas/go/bin/bee, there is one .exe file named bee there. Rest of the things are under github.com folder

Comment: Ohh, you're on Windows?

Comment: No, you're on Mac, how do you have `.exe` file?

Comment: @Z.Kosanovic it is a UNIX executable file

Comment: `.exe` is almost certainly a Windows executable. Mac/Linux/Unix executables have no file extension associated.